# Objective-C Trying to download PDF that is from a short url

Tags: objective-c, pdf, redirect, download, short-url

I have been trying to get this to work without having it load on the web view first and getting the absoluteString from that so I can download the URL. I have tried many shortURL solutions and they never fully load the URL.  They always give me the URL that is not the final url and does not that the PDF url.  Any help would be amazing.  I am trying to download the PDF when the app first opens or when it checks for updates, but at the time it just gets the short url and I have to wait till the web view is called to get the full url to be able to download the PDF a head of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You download the PDF, just like you would download any other file.

Take a look at [NSURLDownload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html)

```
- (void)startDownloadingURL:sender
{
    // Create the request.
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/index.html"]
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                             timeoutInterval:60.0];

    // Create the download with the request and start loading the data.
NSURLDownload  *theDownload = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (!theDownload) {
        // Inform the user that the download failed.
    }
}

- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download decideDestinationWithSuggestedFilename:(NSString *)filename
{
    NSString *destinationFilename;
    NSString *homeDirectory = NSHomeDirectory();

    destinationFilename = [[homeDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Desktop"]
        stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    [download setDestination:destinationFilename allowOverwrite:NO];
}


- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Dispose of any references to the download object
    // that your app might keep.
    ...

    // Inform the user.
    NSLog(@"Download failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (void)downloadDidFinish:(NSURLDownload *)download
{
    // Dispose of any references to the download object
    // that your app might keep.
    ...

    // Do something with the data.
    NSLog(@"%@",@"downloadDidFinish");
}
```

Comment: I tried this, it always ends in an error because it doesn't finish redirecting the URL to get the actual URL to the PDF.  The way I do it now, is I wait for the web view to load so it finishes the redirect and do webView.request.URL.absoluteString.  The thing is that the PDF now downloads when the view loads the PDF.  I want the PDF to download as the application opens, so I need the full URL from the redirect when the app opens.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [AppleDocs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/RequestChanges.html) about handling redirect request.

Answer (score 0):

try using afnetworking to download pdf file in to the server

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://letuscsolutions.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/five-point-someone-chetan-bhagat_ebook.pdf"]];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:120];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    NSString *pdfName = @"2.zip";

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:pdfName];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
     };

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

             NSLog(@"Download = %f", (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead);
            NSLog(@"total bytesread%f",(float)totalBytesRead );
            NSLog(@"total bytesexpected%lld",totalBytesExpectedToRead );

        });


    }];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

    [operation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a method to open a pdf file from an URL with the UIDocumentInteractionController:

```
- (void)openURL:(NSURL*)fileURL{
    //Request the data from the URL
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:fileURL completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error){
        if(!error){
            //Save the document in a temporary file
            NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
            [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
            //Open it with the Document Interaction Controller
            _docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
            _docController.delegate = self;
            _docController.UTI = @"com.adobe.pdf";
            [_docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];

        }
    }] resume];

}
```

And myViewController.h:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>

@property UIDocumentInteractionController *docController;
```